# Trying to create new feature cost anamoly monitor using terraform with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, aws-cost-explorer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntYgV.png)

```
locals {
  AnomalyMonitorName = "all-services-cost-monitor"
  AnomalyMonitor = {
    MonitorName      = local.AnomalyMonitorName
    MonitorType      = "DIMENSIONAL"
    MonitorDimension = "SERVICE"
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "cost_anomaly_monitor" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<CMD
      aws ce create-anomaly-monitor --anomaly-monitor \
        '${jsonencode(local.AnomalyMonitor)}'
    CMD
  }
```

But I m getting below validation error limit exceeded on Dimensional spend monitor creation

Comment: You haven't provide the FULL error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to create more than one "DIMENSIONAL->SERVICES" monitor, as far as I know, it monitors all AWS Services (so it would be redundant to have two monitors checking the same thing, when you try to create a second one on the console it shows the following message: `Only 1 AWS services monitor type can be created for an account. Remove any existing monitors to create a new AWS service monitor.`). If you were to create a monitor of type CUSTOM it should let you.

Check under AWS Cost Management -> Cost Anomaly Detection -> Cost Monitors and it's very likely that you will have a "DIMENSIONAL->SERVICES" monitor in there, delete it and recreate through your Terraform code and should not raise any errors.

PS. When I say "DIMENSIONAL->SERVICES" it will show in your Console as "AWS services", I call it like that because from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ce-anomalymonitor.html) a Monitor of type `DIMENSIONAL` will always have a dimension of `SERVICE`. As a side note, if you are on a linked account you can only create a SERVICE monitor, so make sure you test it on the payer account.